# Laravel - Can't redirect after sending mail

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, view, return

After sending a Mail (which my code does), I want to redirect the user to another view (main.blade.php) but nothing is happening.

In my form, I call the sendemail route, here is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('sendemail') }}">
```

In my web.php the routes are defined as following:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@main')->name('main');
Route::post('/sendemail', "SendEmailController@send")->name('sendemail');
```

And my *SendEmailController.php* looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class SendEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function send()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name'     =>  'required',
            'email'  =>  'required|email',
            'message' =>  'required',
            'company' => 'required',
            'knowledge' => 'required',
            'reason' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required'
        ]);
        Mail::to('example@example.eu')->send(new SendMail($data));

        return redirect()->to('main');    
   }
}
```

Have read this topic : [Redirect to contacts page after submitting form in laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898883/redirect-to-contacts-page-after-submitting-form-in-laravel-4)

But didn't work for me.

**EDIT:**

The problem did not came from Laravel but from AJAX, problem solved.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the blade form, the route and the full controller method

Comment: Yes sure @Ballard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to` method accepts path, not route name. It will work with

```
return redirect()->to('/');
```

To use route name in redirection you have to use

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes).

Comment: I just tried with both of your answers and none of them worked for me

Comment: What happens when you try? Include more details because _doesn't work_ can't be abstracted as an error. What is written in log file?

Comment: My log file is empty and nothing is happening on the screen, no error no message

Comment: here is my code `public function main(){
        return view('main');
    }`

Comment: `main` view blade file is not empty? Or can you set something like `echo 123;` in `main` file and confirm it return valid response?

Comment: my main file isn't empty as it is the home page. From that page you can go in another page where you can find the form i used to send a mail

Comment: No reason my solution wouldn't work. For curiosity sake, try `redirect()->action('PagesController@main')`. Also double check namespaces in files.

Comment: I don't understant too. I tried your code and again, nothing happening and my log file is still empty

Comment: Exclude sending mail from debugging for now. Does it work when you commented mailing code there in `send()` method?

Comment: well, I excluded all my code in the send() function and tried with all your answers, none of them gave me something different than before. (my mail isn't sent as expected)

Comment: I tried the code you gave me and in my log file there is only the debug from finally block part with an array containing the $data variable

Comment: Now try to set `return redirect()->to('/non-existing-path');` in finally block instead.

Comment: My loading animation isn't stopping and i got this error in the browser console:`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: I assume then you missed to mention if you're using AJAX.

Comment: I will checkout tomorow with my coworker if and where AJAX is used and I will edit my post, thank you for your answers so far

Comment: Although it raises other question compared to initial question. However, there was the error in initial question that my answer solves. Regarding AJAX, it (AJAX) expects some string in return but gets redirect instead. If my assumption is correct you need to return json response from send method and on status 200 to manually redirect with JS (i.e. location.href function) to home page. To have this working you need to prevent default form behavior in that submit event.

Comment: I asked my teamates and indeed there is some AJAX used in my project and it was blocking any redirection, I just changed the js code and now my project works ! Thank You